# What are the appropriate names for the parts of a docker image's name?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Given `my-registry/my-image:0.1.0`

- `my-registry` is the registry
- `my-image` is the name?
- `0.1.0` is the tag? version?
- `my-image:0.1.0` is the name? The image?
- `my-registry/my-image:0.1.0` is the fully-scoped name?

Are there any "officially" sanctioned ways to distinguish between those parts? My use case is: when I write scripts that figure out the right parameters to do Docker builds, I always struggle to find proper ways to distinguish e.g. "my-image" from "my-image:tag"

Answer (score 4):

According to [the reference for `docker tag`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/tag/#extended-description):

> An image name is made up of slash-separated name components, optionally prefixed by a registry hostname.

The tag is generally regarded as the part after the `:`. As such, though ignoring the case of more than 2 slash-separated components:

- `my-registry` is the registry
- `my-registry/my-image` is the (image) name
- `0.1.0` is the tag (name)

There don't seem to be names for the units `my-registry/my-image:0.1.0`, `my-image` and `my-image:0.1.0` (other than `my-image` being called a "name component"). You could conceivably call `my-registry/my-image:0.1.0` the tagged name, and if you took the approach of calling `my-image` the project (which is my personal approach) then you could call `my-image:0.1.0` the tagged project.

Note that, despite the above, `docker image` refers to the `my-registry/my-name` unit as a "repository". I personally prefer to use the "name" terminology for this unit.

Answer (score 1):

To build a Docker image you would have to do as following:

`docker build -t my-registry/the-image-name:tag`

(where tag can be anything you would like such as: image type (debian, centos, nginx, myApp, lb, php and so on).

The version isn't a must, but if you don't pass a version tag such as (v1, 1.0.0) you would be always building the image with the `latest` tag such as:

```
my-registry/the-image-name:myApp
```

whereas, if you pass a `tag` it will be easier to keep track of the Docker images that you are building:

```
my-regsitry/the-image-name:myApp-v1.0.0
```

[Image Tag Best Practices](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux_atomic_host/7/html/recommended_practices_for_container_development/naming)

[Docker Image Tags](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/an-introduction-to-docker-tags-9b5395636c2a)

[Docker Image Tags 2](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/stevelasker/2018/03/01/docker-tagging-best-practices-for-tagging-and-versioning-docker-images/)